# Scroll to section add css class to progress bar jquery

Tags: jquery

Hey new to jquery and have been trying to figure this out for wayyyy too long now.

Without add a ton of code on, How would you add a css class to the progress bar when a user has scrolled to a section of the page? I've been trying yo capture when the user scrolls down but maybe I'm not going about this the right way?....

This was my last attempt at this, but I desperately tried to put save a function and then call it again in another section. The thing also the set time function works and I did get it to fill but only after a certain set time not by scroll......

```
var section = $(window).scroll( function() {
  var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
   var scrolled_val = $(document).scrollTop().valueOf();
   console.log(scrolled_val+ ' = scroll value');
  });


  if (scrolled_val == 1469) {
    setTimeout(function(section) {
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', '30%');
    }, 500);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of stuff going on in your code that I don't understand. Here's the most straightforward way of doing it:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() == 1469)
        $(".progress-bar").addClass("my-new-class");
});
```

You probably also want to add in a tolerance factor (it's rare that a user would scroll exactly to a certain `scrollTop`) and you probably also want to remove the class later (`progressBar.removeClass("my-new-class")`). If you need more help with either of these, I'd be happy to provide some code.

Comment: def not working, that prob the first thing I tried doing.....I even console.log my scroll count and still nothing. This seems like the most simple thing but the toughest thing to do for some reason... Al I want is when a user scrolls down to the part of the progress bar that the inside fills up @ShengSlogar

Comment: @CarlSergile The only thing I could imagine going wrong here is you're not scrolling to exactly `1469 px` on the page. Could you throw your code into a JSFiddle or such? That would make it a lot easier to debug. :)

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: @CarlSergile Clarify: what are you referring to by that?